# Boost library simple compilation with tuples

Tags: c++, boost

Can anyone tell me why this works (compiles and runs)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
//#include <boost/tuple.hpp>
//#include <boost/tuple_comparison.hpp>
//#include <boost/tuple_io.hpp>
using namespace boost;

int main ( )
{
//  tuple<int, char, float> t(2, 'a', 0.9);
//  std::cout << t << std::endl;
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> m1;
     return 0;
 }
```

but when I uncomment the lines related to tuple, it says

> boost_tuple.cpp:3:27: fatal error: boost/tuple.hpp: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

I use the following to compile in both cases:

> g++ -Wall -c -I/usr/include/boost boost_tuple.cpp

And I also checked that `/usr/include/boost/tuple.hpp` exists

Comment: Syntax highlighting is somewhat automatic; for details, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include it as:

```
#include <boost/tuple.hpp>
```

**lose** the `boost` part in `-I/usr/include/boost`. Right now this is being evaluated as `/usr/include/boost/boost/tuple.hpp`, which is probably your problem.

**EDIT:**

Make sure tuple.hpp is installed where you said it is, because on my system it's located in another folder: `/usr/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp`

Which means that I need to include the file as `#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>` and compile it as:

```
g++ tuple.cpp -o tuple -I /usr/include/boost
```

**tuple.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main ( )
{
    tuple<int, char, float> t(2, 'a', 0.9);
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> m1;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Hmm .. that does not seem to be the problem. I am able to run the code with comments (using either -I/usr/include and -I/usr/include/boost) .. but none of them work after un-commenting the part about tuples.

Comment: Updated my answer, please review it carefully. By the way, you can't print a tuple like you were trying to do. `std::cout` can only understand strings and literals, not tuple objects.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, that was the problem! And the std::cout also works for tuple object!!